# Finding highest correlated stocks to a specific point in R with weekly data

Tags: r, correlation

I have tried to find an answer for this everywhere and there is a lot of stock correlation answers but nothing revolving around a single point.

My goal is to find which 5 stocks had the highest correlation to a specific stock ID. The dataset is split weekly over 10 years.

I have tried splitting the datasets into two: 1) dataset without the stock I need 2) dataset with the specific stock.

I know I need to do a weekly comparison of all the stocks to this specific stock and somehow find which was most correlated over the timeframe.

It is roughly clear in my head; however, I have been stuck at the implementation because I am not sure how to group the weeks and compare it to a single week and so on.

Ultimate goal: compare all the stocks of the first week to the first line of the second table and so on.

### Many thanks!

PS: This isn't a university assignment, I am just trying to improve my coding skills

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data aren't very helpful because we can't copy/paste the data in to R.

Comment: Dear @MrFlick,

Apologies, it is my first time posting here. I have attach some of the code i used to split up the data to get the stock I want. I hope this what you were asking for, I am not sure how to give you a sample dataset, please let me know and I will do it right away.

Comment: One way to provide your data would be to paste the `dput()` output of your data set into your question: `dput(stocks)`. If you prefer not to share the full data set you can use `head()` to only share the first few rows: `dput(head(stocks, 20))`.

Comment: @Till Thank you so much! I have reedited my post to include the code i have used + the dput function you've recommended

Comment: You included the `dput()` command in your code, but what we need is the output, to be able to help you. When you execute dput(stocks) you'll see output in the console starting with `structure(...` please copy and paste this code into your question, preferably in a separate code section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the data transformation steps, to out your data set into a state
where you can calculate correlations easily:

1. Extract week and year from the Date column, to create a week identifier unique
   accross years (`week()` and `year()` are `lubridate` functions).
2. Drop Date column.
3. Make the dataset wide, so that the value for each stock is in a separate
   column (`pivot_wider()` is a `tidyr` function).

Code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

week_stocks <-
  stocks %>%
  mutate(Week = paste(year(Date), week(Date), sep = "_")) %>%
  select(StockID, Value, Week) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = StockID, values_from = Value)
```

After the transformation you use `cor()` to get correlations of all stocks.
Since you are only interested in the correlations with one specific stock,
you can use `select()` to drop all other stocks and their correlations.

```
cor(week_stocks[-1]) %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "stockIDs") %>%
  select(stockIDs, `210449`)
```

Some general remarks:

1. In the code in your question you use the `attach()` command, it is generally
   not recommended to use that for data frames, as it can lead to confusion and
   errors; [see this blogpost](http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2011/05/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SASandR+%28SAS+and+R%29).
2. If you are looking into improving your R Skills check out the
   [tidyverse](http://www.tidyverse.org) and it’s packages. It is a great set of packages
   which share a concept for data science operations, that is very powerful and allows you
   to solve most data science problems with a small set of concise commands.
3. When asking a question on StackOverflow it is usually good practice to
   include your data or at least parts of it. `dput()` provides the code needed
   for that. By pasting the output of `dput()` into your question other users
   can recreate your data in their environment and develop their answer while testing
   their code against your data. For example this is what the `dput()` output of
   my dummy dataset looks like, I used to create the code in my answer.

Code:

```
dput(stocks)
```

Output:

```
structure(list(StockID = c(16139, 210449, 210449, 210449, 210449, 
210449), Date = c("2015-09-11", "2015-09-11", "2015-09-18", "2015-09-25", 
"2015-10-02", "2015-10-09"), Value = c(0.055063, 0.01851903, 
0.01338099, 0.03982749, 0.04798457, 0.02433628)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it worked! I appreciate it and thank you for the general tips, noted